# SELinux: allow socat to run on unreserved_port_t

Tags: selinux, yocto

I'm working on an embedded distro with SELinux.

I am having this issue:

```
root@unknown7:~# socat openssl-listen:7777,reuseaddr, stdio
2022/02/03 13:44:44 socat[2331] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:7777}, 16): Permission denied
```

While audit2allow suggest adding this line to policies:

```
allow sysadm_t unreserved_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;
```

But doing so would make the SELinux policies not compile:

```
| Compliling mls sysadm.mod module
| policy/modules/roles/sysadm.te:54:ERROR 'unknown type unreserved_port_t' at token ';' on line 25502:
| allow sysadm_t unreserved_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;
| allow sysadm_t node_t:tcp_socket node_bind;
| [...]/usr/bin/checkmodule:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
| [...]/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/checkmodule:  loading policy configuration from tmp/sysadm.tmp
| make: *** [tmp/sysadm.mod] Error 1
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at [...]/tmp/work/namc_p2041-fsl-linux/refpolicy-mls/git-r0/temp/log.do_compile.14399)
ERROR: Task 2020 ([...]/sources/meta-selinux/recipes-security/refpolicy/refpolicy-mls_git.bb, do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3770 tasks of which 3746 didn't need to be rerun and 2 failed.
Waiting for 0 running tasks to finish:

Summary: 2 tasks failed:
  [...]sources/meta-selinux/recipes-security/refpolicy/refpolicy-standard_git.bb, do_compile
  [...]/QorIQ-SDK-V2.0-20160527-yocto/sources/meta-selinux/recipes-security/refpolicy/refpolicy-mls_git.bb, do_compile
Summary: There were 4 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

My questions:

1. Is there a way to open all ports with SELinux? I know that this is against the principle of having SELinux in the first place, but it's for development purposes only.
2. Is there any way to open only the unrestricted_port_t while keeping the restriction on the other reserved port_t?
3. I want to allow accessing only a handful of ports (7777, 7778, etc). How should I declare them in the policies? Should I create new .te, .fc, .if files?

Comment: I haven't done this yet, but it seems like it'd make more sense to apply a type to that (those) port(s), then allow `socat` to use that type. See for example `semanage port -l` where other ports have defined types instead of "unreserved"